# symfony knp_snappy.pdf doesn't make link in a-tag

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

This is my code:

```
$html = $this->renderView('@App/pdf/default.html.twig', [
    'item' => $item
]);
return new PdfResponse(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
    StringManipulation::slugify($item->getName()) . '.pdf'
);
```

That's show tag a in pdf-file like a text, not link. How can i make it as link?

Comment: Is it an absolute URL?

Comment: @Preciel yes, only absolute URL's

Comment: Please post the code of your default.html.twig.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was in `wkhtmltopdf` binary with `qt`.